# Spring integration: exception is not thrown to error channel

Tags: java, exception, spring-integration, throw, exceptionhandler

I have spring integration channels, the one of them is dbSavingChannel. And I would intercept the thrown exception in my exception handler 'handleErroredMsg', but the program reaches the line 'throw new RuntimeException("conflict");' and does not reach the exception handler. What do I need to do that to intercept exception correctly?

```
    @Async("myExecutor")
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "dbSavingChannel")
    public void saveEntityToDb(final Message<ObjEntity> msg) {
        ObjEntity entity = msg.getPayload();
        List<ObjEntity> conflictList = repository.findAllById(entity.getId());
        if (!conflictList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("conflict");
        }
        ...
    }
    

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public Message<?> errorHandling(final Message<MessageHandlingException> msg) {
        return errorHandler.handleErroredMsg(msg);
    }
```

```
    @Bean("myExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncEsppExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(cores);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(cores);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("eThread-");
        return executor;
    }
```

ErrorHandler:

```
    public Message<?> handleErroredMsg(Message<MessageHandlingException> msg) {
        Throwable cause = msg.getPayload().getCause();
        ...
    }
```

The exception appears in the console but is not caught in the handler.

If I remove @Async("myExecutor") - It works, but how can I handle exception with using @Async ?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Async("myExecutor")` is not a part of Spring Integration. If you'd like to do that Spring Integration way (I mean async process), then you need to look into making that `dbSavingChannel` as an `ExecutorChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/implementations.html#executor-channel.

Then Spring Integration wraps that provided `TaskExecutor` to the `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` - and an `ErrorMessage` is going to be sent to the global `errorChannel`.

If you still would prefer to use `@Async`, then you need to use that `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` manually and supply it with the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/error-handling.html